# mysql how to output the auto_increment counter value

Tags: mysql

When i insert a record into a table, the auto_increment field 's value maybe 1000, I know there is a auto_increment counter, deciding the value.

I use the command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_incre%'
```

it outputs：

```
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
```

so I just want to know, if there is a way i can use to check the auto_increment counter value. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'
```

Gives you the column as Auto_increment. This is the next value (often id) which will be added on INSERT.

Example:

```
$str_table = 'users';

$query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '{$str_table}'");
$row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$int_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the table is shown in the table DDL. Try `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`auto` (
`ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`NAME` CHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test`.`auto` (`ID`, `NAME`) VALUES (NULL, 'A');
INSERT INTO `test`.`auto` (`ID`, `NAME`) VALUES (NULL, 'B');

SHOW CREATE TABLE test.auto;

CREATE TABLE `auto` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `NAME` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: I find Robin's solution more elegant, though.