# How to recive the last row id in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to receive the last row id in the database without generating a new row or updating the row.

Just to read the last id?

I have the function `mysql_insert_id` and need something like this, but without generating a new row.

Comment: show me your code what u tried??

Comment: I'm curious why you would ever want to do this... it rather suggests poor design somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS latest_id
FROM table_name
```

If you instead want the comming (and not yet existing) id without inserting a row, [see my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409424/mysql-how-to-output-the-auto-increment-counter-value/10409454#10409454).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `max()` function like

```
select max(yourcol) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try lot of queries for that :-

```
  select * from TABLE_NAME order by ID desc limit 1;
```

"or"

```
SELECT * 
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE);
```

Comment: `top 1 *` doesn't work in mysql; it's `limit 1`. You have given SQL Server Syntax.

Comment: Then you haven't red the post properly. OP is asking for MYSQL and not MSSQL.

Comment: Check your query once `select limit 1 *` ... should be `select * from TABLE_NAME order by ID desc limit 1;`

Comment: Hmm ... you realised your mistake but late. I don't know about other downvoter but I am calling off my one.